When I say "I" what am I referring to? Mind, Consciousness, flesh?
I cant be referring to flesh when i say "I" as there is something deeper, so what do you guys think? If i point at a human and say that is joe, is "Joe" the flesh of the human?

Hello and welcome to this site. This site is dedicated to asking about works and writings of philosophy mainly, not "philosophic questions". Natural language is ambiguous, so words can take multiple meanings. In general it cannot be known for sure what a speaker means unless the speaker reveals what they meant. So you could improve your question by first reading about philosophy of personal identity, and then asking about what you read, if you still need to.

Oh okay so questions about the works of other philosophers, but not shower-thought like questions?

We get those, too, and they often get answers as well, but they are not the purpose of this site.

If you are saying it then you tell us what you are referring to. And why should it be the same each time? Pronouns like "I" commonly refer to different things in different contexts. "I" surely can refer to the body, e.g. when someone says "I am standing on the grass" or "I am wounded".

"One I sets the alarm clock at night  and another I wakes up in the morning and says 'Who set that alarm? ''" -- attributed to Baba Ram Das. It has been said that "who am I" (and who am I not) is the ultimate question of all literature, and that SF takes it a step farther by asking what (else) each of those words might mean.

Scottish philosopher David Hume came up with his bundle theory for identity. He thought the mind is a collection (or a bundle) of thoughts, emotions, feelings and perceptions, that are constantly, endlessly changing. All these things together make up you. And that is it. You’re just that because there is nothing else. The next passage is from his Treaty of Human Nature. For understanding the text it helps to know that Hume had a broad interpretation of ‘perceptions’. Here they also include thoughts and emotions. It seems strange to think of thoughts as perceptions, but when you think about it, it makes sense: in a way your thoughts bubble up and you become aware of them. You perceive them as it were.

For my part, when I enter most intimately into what I call myself, I always stumble on some particular perception or other, of heat or cold, light or shade, love or hatred, pain or pleasure. I never can catch myself at any time without a perception, and never can observe any thing but the perception…. If any one, upon serious and unprejudic'd reflection thinks he has a different notion of himself, I must confess I can reason no longer with him. All I can allow him is, that he may be in the right as well as I, and that we are essentially different in this particular. He may, perhaps, perceive something simple and continu'd, which he calls himself; tho' I am certain there is no such principle in me.

Hume’s scepticism when it comes to the self is astonishing. There is no such principle in me! He wrote this in the 18th century. It is no suprise that he was accused of heresy and atheism. You can read more here.
I think he nailed it.

And Theravada Buddhism has similar idea of Anatta (no self) - that you are "5 aggregates" of perception. Like you, I think this is the right idea, but we like to think there is something special behind it all.

@Annika I have read about Anatta, but I don't see how Buddhism reconciles 'no self' with the doctrine of Karma. If there is no self, then what accumulates Karma and what transcends this life? I think there are many deep truths in Buddhism, but the transmigration part I find difficult to take on board.

Personal pronouns refer to a person (duh), or anything like a person (intelligent agents). In stories, ghosts and demons without bodies are persons, fantasy characters are referenced by pronouns, and AI assistants may also use "I". Typically person have bodies though, and so sometimes it also refers to bodies, even of bodies without any agency (like dolls).
In philosophy of mind, personal identity is a complex topic with different definitions for different contexts as well, see

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/identity-personal/
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_identity

Given there is no complete consensus about whether there is anything objective that has an identity that a pronoun could refer to, personal identity is at the minimum a construct (something we imagine and or define), which might or might not have a corresponding target in reality.
Even in materialism, that which a pronoun points to might rather be a process than a material thing. With the assumption of body-mind dualism, a mind could be meant to be referenced.
Spirituality may redefine any notion as well, such as with reincarnation, of the Dalai Lama, different people get to be the same person, in a way.
With phenomena like dissociative identity disorders (also known as multiple personalities) or split brain events, pronoun meanings are also problematic.

Typically you refer to a person, who is both body and mind. As always, the precise meaning will depend on context. Eg in "You want a piece of me?" "me" refers to "my body". But in "I think therefore I am", "I" refers to "my mind".

It's an excellent question, and as usual, the comments are all about whether it's worthy of being asked.
"Me" doesn't refer to one's mind or body, because you can say, "MY mind" and "MY body."
The referent isn't explicitly defined. It's whoever made the statement, as in, "the present writer" or "I think, therefore I am."
We use this linguistic trick in the 3rd person too, when we say, "It is morning" or "It is raining."
What is raining? The sky? The air?
No, the statement means, "Whatever it is that's raining, is raining water down on us."
Grammarians call this kind of construction a "dummy pronoun." Computer programmers call it an "unbound variable."
Statements like this take the form: A has attribute B. But the information being transmitted is about the attribute B, not the entity A.
It's a statement about context, not about an object.
"Her hair is dark" is a statement about hair. But at night, "It is dark" refers to darkness, not to an object's luminosity.

Ok, it is not the sky that is raining; it is the rain that is raining. Thus, when I say "I'm walking" there is no me: it is the walk that is walking.

@MauroALLEGRANZA > when I say "I am walking,"  it is the walk that is walking.  === Wrong again, Albert. In that case, the pronoun "I" is not unbound. It refers to a specific person, yourself
